# copy data from one table to another with the same column names by syscolumn

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables A and B. They have **same column names but different type**.
Now I want to **copy data from A to B**. But **I don't want to specify the column names**. I want to use **syscolumns** like this:

`select name from syscolumns where id=object_id(N'A')`

My sql query structure like:

`insert into B(dynamicColumnNames...) 
selec dynamicColumnNames... from A`

I want to know **how to replace the dynamicColumnNames part with syscolumns name**.

By the way, **please don't use store procedure**.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following script (be sure that you know what you are doing, its not so good aproach :) ):

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)


WITH CTE AS (
            SELECT STUFF((
                        SELECT ', ' + cast(a.COLUMN_NAME as varchar(2000))
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
                        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b ON a.COLUMN_NAME = b.COLUMN_NAME
                        WHERE a.TABLE_NAME = 'A' AND 
                              b.TABLE_NAME = 'B' 
                        FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,'') AS Cols
            )

SELECT @cmd = 'INSERT INTO A ('+CTE.Cols+') SELECT '+CTE.Cols+' FROM B'
FROM CTE

EXEC (@cmd)
```

This script do not solving convert to correct types... but it is possible to do that from INFORMATION_SCHEMA also...